# How to import dateutil?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am missing something obviously simple here, but I can't say what : I need your fresh eyes to tell me :)

```
$ pip install python-dateutil
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Cleaning up...
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>>> import dateutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

How to import dateutils ??

Comment: PS: with an (s), import dateutils fail too :(

Comment: Running the same commands works fine for me. Check your Python installation and make sure that the above directory is in your import path. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751292/how-to-get-current-import-paths-in-python

Comment: Your pip might not be pointing to the same python you're using. You're using the system python in Mac, ensure your pip comes from the same framework.

Comment: Also check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16675907/963881

Comment: Either your paths are pointing to inconsistent places, or your install/permissions are corrupt. This is a duplicate of many questions here. Frankly, if all else fails, just uninstall and reinstall dateutil. Unless you found a new symptom, this question should be closed-as-duplicate.

Comment: Like Meitham said, probably firs check your default python version, your pip might be pointing to a different python version. there's one test you can do here: `$ pip-2.7 install dateutil` then try above again.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause might be that **python** and **pip** do not match.

You can check their versions.

```sh
pip -V
python -V
pip2 -V
```

[image: check the version]

As you can see, python and pip do not match. **pip** is for **python3** and **python** is for **python2**.

Hence, the solution should be

```sh
pip2 install python-dateutil
```